# Uncaught TypeError: a.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation-5

I'm developing a site locally on `ModX` using `Foundation5` as the framework, and employing Foundation's `offcanvas` menu. `Offcanvas` has functioned perfectly since its implementation a couple of weeks ago. Today, fired up `MAMP` and the site and in the console is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.getAttribute is not a function
```

It relates to the a tag used to trigger the offcanvas menu and `jquery.min.js`.

I don't even know where to begin. Everything was in order last night, and today the first thing that happens is that this error appears.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Determined that a ModX extra was being triggered and inserting an older version of jquery.